# Tkinter Scrollbar jumps to top of listbox after selection

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

I have a scrollbar for a listbox, and when a selection is made past the original view of the listbox (you scroll down to select something), after the selection, the scrollbar jumps to the top of the listbox.  I  want the listbox to stay in the location it's currently at just how any other general scrollbar works. Here's the definition of the listbox

```
def createListBox(self):
    self.frame = Frame(self)#Frame that holds the scrollbar and listbox
    self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.frame)
    self.waiver_menu = Listbox(self.frame, width = 20, height = 9, yscrollcommand = self.scrollbar.set)
    self.scrollbar.config(command = self.waiver_menu.yview)
    self.frame.grid(row = self.row_count, column = self.col_count, rowspan = 3)
    self.waiver_menu.grid(row = self.row_count, column = self.col_count, rowspan = 3)
    self.scrollbar.grid(row = self.row_count, column = self.col_count+1, rowspan = 3, sticky = N+S+W)

    self.waiver_menu.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.chosen)
```

Comment: Works for me. Windows 10, python 3.5. Double-clicked on the 20th item, it selected it, and the Listbox view was still on the 20th item.

Comment: Please provide more code. This function is not enough to sort out your issue as it works fine on my end as well. The problem might be somewhere else in your code. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry for insufficient code. Thanks for your help. I didn't think it was somewhere else, but I forgot I was refreshing the listbox in another location which was causing the scrollbar to jump to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was refreshing the listbox in another location by deleting and inserting new items which is why it brings you back to the top. This definition of the listbox with scrollbar implementation works!